# Given a table with events happening on a specific time; how do I divide the time into frequencies and count them

Tags: python, dataframe, time, data-science

I've been given a table with card accidents and at which time they occurred (Format HH:MM).

I want to create a new column in the DF where the time is an interval of 15 minutes (ex. 10:30 - 10:45).

With that information, I want to create a count plot that counts the number of accidents for each time interval.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to use date time library :

```
import datetime
```

To get your time in the right format just use the `split()` function

```
hour = your_hour_from_table.split(':')
```

And you will get a list where hour[0] is HH and hour[1] is MM.
Then create a list with all your time slots :

```
time_slots = ["10:00 - 10:15", "10:15 - 10:30",...]
```

And also a dictionary with the time slots as keys (**use the same string as in time_slots list**) and 0 as initial value:

```
hour_dictionary = {"10:00 - 10:15":0, "10:15 - 10:30":0,...}
```

Use a for-loop to verify in which time slot your accident was (assuming your accident is stored in `accident_hour` variable) :

```
def verify_time_slot(accident_hour):
    for i in time_slots:

        slot_first_hour = i.split(' - ')[0].split(':')[0]
        slot_first_minute = i.split(' - ')[0].split(':')[1]

        slot_second_hour = i.split(' - ')[1].split(':')[0]
        slot_second_minute = i.split(' - ')[1].split(':')[1]

        hour_accident = accident_hour.split(':')[0]
        minute_accident = accident_hour.split(':')[1]

        if datetime.time(slot_first_hour, slot_first_minute, 0) <= datetime.time(hour_accident, minute_accident, 0) <= datetime.time(slot_second_hour, slot_second_minute, 0):
            hour_dictionary[i] += 1
```

So with this function you can verify the time slots and store them. Then use also a for-loop to to this with every accident_hour you have.

I let you finish the exercise yourself to enter all this informations in a table, I think the main algorithm is already in your hands.

Comment: Thanks Axel, I think this should absolutely work.

I'm having one issue though. I get "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'" when applying the first function. How can I solve that.

Comment: It means you don't have your time in HH:MM format (in string) but you already have a DateTime object. It simplifies everything because you can easily compare those time with others without converting them to a DateTime object and split the string to get 'hour' and 'minute'